# How do you make multiple project starts visual studio sln sync via git?

Tags: visual-studio

I know how to set it so multiple projects run on play as part of a solution. However on make this change the .sln file clearly does not change meaning on a clean pull from the git repo I always have to go into properties and change the setting again.

How do I fix this?

I have tried saving a filter
Clean and rebuild solution
Build Solution

Nothing changed

Comment: Git is not aware of solutions. You can put multiple solutions into a single Git repository; Git will continue to be blithely unaware of the solutions. You can split one solution across multiple Git repositories, but that's not recommended. (I only know the Git side of this; I don't know what buttons you press in VS thingies.)

Comment: Where are the properties stored then? How is git unaware as I can sync the sln files to the repo, but clearly there are things not in the sln file (which isn't part of my gitignore)

Comment: They're in `.sln` files, which Git just stores as files. I understand that the usual trick to have multiple solutions is to create `proj1/.sln`, `proj2/.sln`, etc., in a repository that holds `proj1/*` and `proj2/*` files. (Note that Git deals with files one-commit-at-a-time: extracting a file extracts all its files, and making a new commit makes a new commit that contains every file. Git de-duplicates *content* so this repeated committing of the same files over and over takes no space at all, in most cases.)